# adding JLabels to JFrame during adding new records to Map

Tags: java, dictionary, jframe, jlabel

I want to add new JLabels to JFrame with number and currenct date when I add new records to my Map.

I'm trying to create app in Java swing which will display new records in JLables in my Frame during I add new records to the Map in the second window (window with textField and button). When I add the first record - window will start and display one record, when I add second record in Frame I will see two JLabels. Now I can start first window when in map is one record but when I add next one I don't see nothing more. What is wrong ?
Thanks in advance!

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == button1) {

            //Current date - when click on button
            currentdata = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");

            //Read textfield and save in variable
            licname = nameField.getText();

            //add license number and date of click to Map
            testmap.put(licname, currentdata);
            //Display of map
            System.out.println(testmap);

            //Check if map has only 1 field - if yes application start, windows opens
            if (testmap.size() == 1) {
                Rest rest = new Rest();
                try {
                    rest.getLicense(licname, currentdata);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
           //Check if map has 2 or more fields - add new label
                   else if (testmap.size() > 1) {
   
                   ArrayList<JLabel> labellist = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
                    for (int i = 2; i > testmap.size(); i++) {
                    testlabel = new JLabel();
                        testlabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/images/tab.jpg"));
                        testlabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                        testlabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
                        testlabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
                        testlabel.setBounds(10, 140 + (i * 10), 200, 50);
                    labellist.add(testlabel);
                }
                    JPanel p = new JPanel();
                    for(JLabel j:labellist) {
                        p.add(j);
                    }
                    f.add(p);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: As an aside I strongly recommend that you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes were troublesome and were supplanted nearly 10 years ago for that reason. Today use for example `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: Hi, please clean up the code a bit. I don't understand why the JPanel and JLabels are recreated every time an item is added (after the first). Also, what does `getLicense` do? Is that an add function? Think about descriptive names. And lastly, I would not check against the testmap size but rather if the new window is already visible, you should just need to add the new JLabel to the existing window, and make the window visible if it's not.

Comment: Function getLicense is a function which start JFrame and also serch the data from data bases based on parametr license which I add in TextFrame

Comment: getLicense is a function which start second window when I add the first record in Map and then I would like to add new JLabels when I add new records to map but I can't call getLicense again only one time because this function start window

Comment: You seem to be mixing the modeling of your data and its presentation. Worse, lines like *licname = nameField.getText();* suggest that you're even deriving the data from the presentation in some way ('global' variables are not good either btw). I would keep these layers of your program quite separate. Yes, they can *interact*, but at the moment they don't appear sufficiently separated from the outset

Comment: `testlabel.setBounds(10, 140 + (i * 10), 200, 50);` ← You can remove that line, because it does nothing.  The parent JPanel’s layout determines the size and location of its children.  The initial layout of a JPanel created with [the zero-argument JPanel constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPanel.html#%3Cinit%3E()) is a FlowLayout, which I suspect is why you don’t see all of your labels.  For a vertical stack of labels, you probably want a GridLayout or a BoxLayout.